# Black screen during outgoing call on Galaxy S3

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3, calls

I made software update for my Galaxy S3 to 4.1.1 and now after outgoing call the screen remains black and doesn't cancel the call or does anything till call stop. I did factory reset but it doesn't resolve my problem. Can anyone help me with that thxon advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it by this:  Call settings ~> Auto screen off/on during calls.