# How to keep my screen light on during the call (Nexus 4, Android 5.1.1)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, nexus-4

I have a Nexus 4 (Android 5.1.1). My proximity sensor does not work well. I don't have any cover. The distance it detects is always 0 cm.

1. One solution I found is turn on "Power button ends call". However I
   need use my keyboard during the call.
2. I also tried some proximity sensor reset apps, but they do not work
   on my phone.
3. One
   [solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33296/black-screen-during-outgoing-call-on-galaxy-s3)
   I found is to keep the screen light on. But I don't have this
   setting on my phone.

Is there any other way to keep my screen light on during the call or other solutions? Thanks

Comment: See if this helps: [Screen turns off during call due to problem with proximity sensor - Xperia Z3 compact](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/133160) (both question and the answers there).

Comment: It does not work... But still thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and had to replace the sensor (I gave up on software solutions).
The sensor is very easy to replace but you need to buy it (I received it from a broken Nexus 4, which had the sensor working fine!)